# Saving selected orders based on the ID of the Delivery object

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a `Delivery Create View` in which I select `Orders` to add to that `Delivery`. However, it doesn't seem to want to save the **linkage** in the database. The `Delivery` gets created because I can see it there if I go back into the program, but the problem lies with getting the `Orders` to link onto that `Delivery`.

It keeps kicking me out when I click save after all the details for delivery have been entered and the orders I want have been selected.

The problem seems to lie with this line when I try to save                 `order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;`and the error message is "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HealthHabitat.dll but was not handled in user code". I've googled a bit around this but I'm not sure how to fix it with regards to my situation.

Please bare in mind that I'm fairly new to Asp.Net MVC, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

Create POST Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DeliveryVM model)
{
    Delivery delivery = new Delivery()
    {
    DriverID = model.DriverID,
    Dispatched_Date = DateTime.Now, 
    Dispatched_Time = DateTime.Now

    };
      db.Deliverys.Add(delivery);
      db.SaveChanges();
      // save the selected orders based on the ID of the Delivery object
      IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
      foreach (int ID in selectedOrders)
      {
        Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;
        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID })

;
```

Create View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
    <td style="width:auto">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
    </td>
    <td style="width:auto">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders[i].IsSelected,    Model.Orders[i].Name,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </td>
    <td style="width:auto">
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Orders[i].IsSelected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </td>
    </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this line in my `View` was the problem.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
```

I suppose that it was because the form couldn't pull the `OrderID` because of the `DisplayFor` attribute.

So I changed it to:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
```

and now it works. However, now I can't display the `OrderID`. So in response to that I just added the same line of code underneath the one above and changed the attribute from `HiddenFor` to `DisplayFor` and now it retrieves the `OrderID` and it displays the `OrderID` so I know which one I'm selecting.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Orders[i].ID)
```

This works but if anyone disagrees with this way and has a better alternative please feel free to edit this accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your 'order' variable is not null before assigning to 'order.DeliveryID'.